# My solution of a LeetCode problem giving stack overflow error there but working fine on my Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, singly-linked-list, bubble-sort

I am trying to solve the LeetCode problem [148. Sort List](https://leetcode.com/problems/sort-list/description/) using bubble sort but I am getting an stack overflow error in my solution on the platform while it's working fine on my Eclipse IDE. Why is that and how to fix it?
Here's the code(in Java)-

```
class Solution {
    public ListNode sortList(ListNode head) {
        return bubbleSort(head,size(head)-1,0);
    }

    int size(ListNode head){
        int c=0;
        while(head!=null){
            c++;
            head=head.next;
        }
        return c;
    }

    ListNode point(ListNode head,int index){
        for(int i=0;i<index;i++){
            head=head.next;
        }
        return head;
    }

    public ListNode bubbleSort(ListNode head,int r,int c){
        if(r==0){
            return head;
        }
        if(c<r){
            ListNode first = point(head,c);
            ListNode second = point(head,c+1);
            if(first.val > second.val){
                if(first==head){
                    first.next=second.next;
                    second.next=first;
                    head=second;
                }else{
                    ListNode prev=point(head,c-1);
                    prev.next=second;
                    first.next=second.next;
                    second.next=first;
                }
            }
            return bubbleSort(head,r,c+1);
        }else{
            return bubbleSort(head,r-1,0);
        }
    }
}
```

Ps: I know that the better solution for the problem is via merge sort but I want to know my mistake here.

Comment: *"it's working fine on my Eclipse IDE ..."*  - How did you test it?  How big was the input list you tested it on?  Did you check that it was properly sorted?  How did you check?

Comment: The short answer is that it was a mistake to use recursion.  (Even if there are other bugs as well ...)

Comment: @StephenC I tried testing it by creating an unsorted linked list and then tried sorting it via this code and it gave expected results.

Comment: OK ... so assuming the code is correct, then my "short" answer is correct.  Your mistake is using recursion.  Java stacks are fixed length and are relatively small, and your sort algorithm requires **at least** N stack frames to sort a list of length N.    Convert the code to iterative; i.e. loops.

Comment: (To be honest ... I am having difficulty getting my head around the logic of the code.  But it looks like you might be doing O(N^2) recursion ... which makes the recursion approach even worse.)

Answer (score 0):

As you probably already know, one of the most common causes of a stack overflow error is recursing too deeply into a function. The computer has a limited stack size to keep track of nested function calls, and once you reach that limit it will fail.

Most likely, what has happened is you tested your code with short lists, and because the logic of your code is correct, it worked just fine. However, bubble sort is an O(n^2) algorithm, and because of the way you've implemented it, that means your function could recurse n^2 times the length of the input list. In the LeetCode problem you linked to, it says

> The number of nodes in the list is in the range [0, 5 * 10^4].

When a competitive programming site gives a constraint range like this, you can be almost certain that they will test the bottom of the range, the top of the range, and several values in-between. Your function works fine for small list lengths, but when it gets passed a list 5*10^4 (50,000) nodes long, it will attempt to recurse in the ballpark of 50,000^2 = 2.5 billion times, which would far exceed the stack space of any typical computer.

In contrast, merge sort has a recursion depth that is log(n), which means that even for the largest possible input LeetCode will give you, it would only recurse 16 times. Alternatively, you could refactor your algorithm to use iteration instead of recursion, which would sidestep the problem entirely by not recursing at all. (it will just take a really long time to execute!)

Hope this helps!